# Get the right value in my array

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to save only the DateTime, and DateTimeOriginal in an array list.

When I run this script, I get the following output when I print my arraylist:

```
[(0x0132) ASCII=2010:07:13 00:00:42 @ 174, (0x9003) ASCII=2010:07:13 00:00:42 @ 530]
```

I am trying to only get the following output, like I get with the `print` function:

```
DateTime : 2010:07:13 00:00:42
DateTimeOriginal : 2010:07:13 00:00:42
```

My code:

```
import exifread

f = open('dfround2.jpg', 'rb')

time = []

tags = exifread.process_file(f)
print("Time information: \n")
for tag in tags.keys():
    if 'Image DateTime' in tag:
        print("DateTime : %s" % (tags[tag]))
        time.append(tags[tag])
    if 'EXIF DateTimeOriginal' in tag:
        print("DateTimeOriginal : %s" % (tags[tag]))
        time.append(tags[tag])

print("Tijd: \n", time)
```

What is the best way to store `DateTime` and `DateTimeOriginal` if I have to use them later on? Is it better to put them in a variable? How can I do that?

What I am trying to do is:
Getting the time dates of images and put them in a timeline. So I have to use my output later on in my script, but I don't know how I can store it.

Comment: What do you mean by "arraylist", and where in your code are you printing something whose output looks like that first line?

Comment: Also, are you just asking how you get the same strings for `tags[tag]` that `print` displays with the `%s` specifier? If so, as the docs for `%` explain, it's just calling the `str` function, so you can do the same thing.

Comment: @abarnert print("Tijd: \n", time) Prints the first line. time = [] is my list. With the loop I get metadata from a image but I have to use the time and dates for other things. But how can I use them without putting them in a variable or in a list?

Comment: First, is that really exactly what it prints? Because if so, the `exifread` library is doing something very weird…

Comment: Meanwhile, what do you mean "how can I use them without putting them in a variable or in a list"? You're already using them in the `print` statements, right? If you want to use them _later_, then obviously you'll have to store them in a list or something; why do you not want to?

Comment: @abarnert I want to store them in a list or something ike that, but I only want the DateTimeOriginal : 2010:07:13 00:00:42. But I get now a lot more information back (look the first code line) in my list. How can I just only get the DateTimeOriginal and not the rest of the usless information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same tag instances in both cases, but with different [string representations](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__).

```
print tag        # using tag.__str__
print [tag, tag] # using tag.__repl__ for each element
```

You can either add `str(tag)` to your list, or use `str(element)` when reading them out again.

Example:

```
from exifread import process_file

with open('dfround2.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    tags = process_file(f)
    time = tags['Image DateTime']
    orig = tags['EXIF DateTimeOriginal']
    print [str(time), str(orig)]
    # ['2014:12:05 18:12:09', '2013:07:20 15:53:30']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm only about 80% sure I understand what you're asking, but…

This prints out the string you want:

```
print("DateTimeOriginal : %s" % (tags[tag]))
```

This stores some complex `tag` object that you don't want:

```
time.append(tags[tag])
```

What you want is just the same string you printed out, not the `tag` object.

If you look at the docs for [`printf`-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting), the conversion type `%s` gives you:

> String (converts any Python object using `str()`).

So, if you want to store the same thing that gets printed with `%s`, just call `str()`, the same way it does:

```
time.append(str(tags[tag]))
```

---

I'm not sure why you want to build a list containing the string representations of all the `DateTime` and `DateTimeOriginal` tags interleaved like this, but if that's what you want, that's how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But when I use the time.append(str(tags[tag])). I stil get a lot of data back. I want that when I print(time) I only see the 2 valus: DateTime : 2010:07:13 00:00:42
DateTimeOriginal : 2010:07:13 00:00:42.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.printable` to get just string representations. Actually if you'll check sources of `exifread` you'll see that `str(tag)` returns `printable`.

```
if 'Image DateTime' in tag:
    print("DateTime : %s" % (tags[tag]))
    time.append(tags[tag].printable)
if 'EXIF DateTimeOriginal' in tag:
    print("DateTimeOriginal : %s" % (tags[tag]))
    time.append(tags[tag].printable)
```

Comment: Dude your the best Thanks a lot!